# Django - problem re-adding goods to the basket

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am creating an online store on Djnago. The project has a basket in which you can place goods, as well as remove them. Goods are placed and removed without problems. But, after the product has been placed, after deletion - when re-adding this product (which was deleted) to the basket (the user is always the same) - the product does not appear, what is the problem?
Below is the code of all application files:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import User


class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images')
    category = models.ForeignKey(to=ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Product: {self.name} | Category: {self.category.name}'


class Basket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(to=Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    created_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Корзина для {self.user.username} | Продукт: {self.product.name}'
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from products.models import ProductCategory, Product, Basket
from users.models import User


def index(request):
    context = {
        'title': 'Store',
        'is_prom': True,
    }

    return render(request, 'products/index.html', context)


def products(request):
    context = {
        'title': 'Store - Каталог',
        'products': Product.objects.all(),
        'categories': ProductCategory.objects.all(),
    }

    return render(request, "products/products.html", context)


def basket_add(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    baskets = Basket.objects.filter(user=request.user, product=product)

    if not baskets.exists():
        Basket.objects.create(user=request.user, product=product, quantity=0)
    else:
        basket = baskets.first()
        basket.quantity += 1
        basket.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])


def basket_remove(request, basket_id):
    basket = Basket.objects.get(id=basket_id)
    basket.delete()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from products.views import products, basket_add, basket_remove

app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', products, name='index'),
    path('baskets/add/<int:product_id>/', basket_add, name='basket_add'),
    path('baskets/remove/<int:basket_id>/', basket_remove, name='basket_remove'),
]
```

views.py - (other app, used only to pass context filed with baskets)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import auth, messages
from django.urls import reverse
from users.forms import UserLoginForm, UserRegistrationForm, UserProfileForm
from users.models import User
from products.models import Basket


def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        form = UserLoginForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)


def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Поздравялем! Вы успешно зарегистрированы!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:login'))
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'users/registration.html', context)


def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:profile'))
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)

    context = {
        'title': 'Store - Профиль',
        'form': form,
        'baskets': Basket.objects.filter(user=request.user),
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)


def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

products.html:

```
{% extends "products/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block css %}
<link href="{% static 'vendor/css/products.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-3">

            <h1 class="my-4">Store</h1>
            <div class="list-group">
                {% for category in categories %}
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">{{ category.name }}</a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-3 -->

        <div class="col-lg-9">

            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide my-4" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{% static 'vendor/img/slides/slide-1.jpg' %}" alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{% static 'vendor/img/slides/slide-2.jpg' %}" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{% static 'vendor/img/slides/slide-3.jpg' %}" alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="row">

                {% for product in products %}
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                    <div class="card h-100">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">
                                <a href="#">{{ product.name }}</a>
                            </h4>
                            <h5>{{ product.price }} руб.</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ product.description }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-center">
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="{% url 'products:basket_add' product.id %}">Отправить в корзину</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}

            </div>

            <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
                    <li class="page-item disabled">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Previous</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
<footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Store 2022</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</footer>
{% endblock %}
```

profile.html:

```
    {% extends 'products/base.html' %}
    {% load static %}

    {% block css %}
        <link href="{% static 'vendor/css/profile.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content%}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <h4 class="mt-3 mb-3">Профиль</h4>
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <img width="100" height="100"
                        src="{% if user.image %} {{ user.image.url }} {% else %} {% static 'vendor/img/users/default_avatar.jpg' %} {% endif %}">
                </div>
                <form action="{% url 'users:profile' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.first_name.id_for_lable }}">Имя</label>
                                {{ form.first_name }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.last_name.id_for_lable }}">Фамилия</label>
                                {{ form.last_name }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row mb-2">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                                {{ form.image }}
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="{{ form.image.id_for_lable }}">Выберите изображение</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.username.id_for_lable }}">Имя пользователя</label>
                            {{ form.username }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.email.id_for_lable }}">Адрес электронной
                                почты</label>
                                {{ form.email }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top: 33px;">
                            <input class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit" value="Сохранить">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                {% include 'products/baskets.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

baskets.html

```
{% if baskets %}
    <h4 class="mt-3 mb-3 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
        Корзина <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">3</span>
    </h4>
    {% for basket in baskets %}
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ basket.product.name }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ basket.product.description }}</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item bg-light">
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <input name="basketID" type="number" class="form-control"
                                value="{{ basket.quantity }}" min="0">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">2 390 руб.</div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <a href="{% url 'products:basket_remove' basket.id %}">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-footer">
        <p class="float-left">Итого</p>
        <h4 class="float-right">2 390 руб.</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-success btn-lg float-right" href="../orders/order-create.html">
    Оформить заказ
</a>
{% else %}
<h4 class="mt-3 mb-3 text-center">
    Корзина пуста
{% endif %}
```

I can't suppose what the problem. My code is like author code.

Comment: please clarify the effect: you mean that once you delete a basket on `baskets.html` and afterwards on `products.html` add a product ... then you do not see that new basket/product on `baskets.html`??  The strange thing is that you create a basket for each product separately, you can increase the number for that single product in the basket but you can only remove the whole baske ... is that really what you want. Typically I would expect to add several products to a basket?

Comment: btw in the basket_remove view you should ad the `user=request.user` to the get query, otherwise a user could remove any basket of any user just by manually changing the href on the html and sending the request.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer.

I'm study now and topic with creating basket new for me. I have same code like author, but his code working without problems.
If talking about my problem:

Comment: If talking about my problem:
I have templates like: 
products - it's main page with goods of store.
baskets (why basket*S* - big question for me) - it's just basket, only basket.
profile - this is page where we can look on our data in store + our basket with goods (if basket dosen't has goods - we see only one string "The basket is empty").

Comment: And for exemple, we want to buy jacket. We pushed the button, this lot go to the basket. We click to the profile menu and see - jacket in basket, after we delete this jacket and want once againe to add this jacket. Again to pushing button, again cheking profile - in this moment we don't see this jacket.

Comment: Added jacket - sucsees.
Delete jacket - sucsess.
Again add jacket - lose.
Again delete jacket - basket dosen't has this jacket.

Sorry for my English, I hope I gave good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

it is still difficult to understand the topic - I would recommend you to add some "prints" to `basket_add` and see in the console what really happens:

```
def basket_add(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    baskets = Basket.objects.filter(user=request.user, product=product)

    print("******** in basket_add ******")
    print("******** product: " ,product)
    print("******** baskets: " ,baskets)

    if not baskets.exists():
        print("******** basket does not exist -> create it")
        Basket.objects.create(user=request.user, product=product, quantity=0)
    else:
        print("******** basket exists ->  increase quantity")
        basket = baskets.first()
        basket.quantity += 1
        basket.save()
```

Note: this is not sophisticated debugging (better to use logging) but here the easiest way for you to begin with.

Still some comments to the logic:

- one basket per product is kind of unusual
- on product add, if the basket does not yet exist it is created but with quantity=0
- product remove does not reduce the quantity but delete the entire basket.
- there is an input field in `baskets.html` named `basketID` that contains in fact the quantity:

```
<input name="basketID" type="number" class="form-control"
                                value="{{ basket.quantity }}" min="0">
```